# Define an error class for C++

Tags: c++, class, error-handling

I've been trying to define an error class in C++. I have three files; `main.cpp`, `my_class.h`, `my_class.cpp`. If I tried to compile with the below code, all, of course, in three separate files, I would get a multiple definition error of `my_exception`.

Please note, if I move the entire definition and declaration of `my_exception` into `my_class.cpp`, everything compiles fine and works correctly. Why is this, and how should I write this so that I could put the definition of the exception into the `.h` file? Or should I even put an error class definition into a `.h` file?

`main.cpp`:

```
#include my_class.h
int main(){
    my_class m;
    /* stuff */
}
```

`my_class.h`:

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

#include <iostream>  //irrelevant for this
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

//taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/
class my_exception : public exception{
    virtual const char* what() throw() { return "message";}
} me_err;

class my_class{
    my_class() };
};

#endif // MY_CLASS_H
```

`my_class.cpp`:

```
#include my_class.h
my_class::my_class(){ 
    throw me_err; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need global variable `me_err` and why do want my_exception to be defined together with `my_class` (in the same file)?

Comment: Also, of all bad things which do not trigger immediate errors, having `using namespace std` in header file is one of the worst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is you created a global variable in your header file.  When you compile `main.cpp` and `my_class.cpp` each one of them now has the same global variable.  To fix this you can make `me_err` a member of `my_class` since that is what is using it.

Edit:

As pointed out by [Fred Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10077/fred-larson) you could get rid of `me_err` entirely and just use `throw my_exception;`

Comment: Does `me_err` need to exist at all? Why not just `throw my_exception;`?